# Prolog If Statement

Tags: prolog, backtracking

I have this code:

```
search(A,[],[]).

search(A,B,C) :-
    select(L1,B,L2),
    select(Name,L1,[Res|_]),
    search(A,L2,T),!,
    (member(A,Res)) -> append([Name],T,C); append([],T,C),  
    sort(C).
```

When it gets to `member(A,Res)`, if it fails it should execute `append([],T,C)` and continue on. If it succeeds it should do `append([Name],T,C)` and move on... correct?

But this is not the case. It attempts to backtrack, regardless of me having a ! operator before it!

What am I not seeing?

Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: You probably want `(member(A,Res) -> append([Name],T,C); append([],T,C))` instead due to operator precedence. Otherwise, the entire block after `;` is considered in the "else". If your `member(A,Res)` succeeds, it will skip the `sort`. By the way, `append([Name], T, C)` can be done simply with `[Name|T] = C` and `append([], T, C)` is just `T = C`.

Comment: also, sort/1 doesn't exist at all...

Comment: Replace `append([], T, C)` by `T = C`